# How to take the selection of a JavaScript dropdown menu and put it in a label in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have this JavaScript for a dropdown menu, but I don't know how to take the selected value from it.

```
<select name="slist" >
   <script language="javascript">
      var states = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antarctica");
       for (var hi = 0; hi < states.length; hi++)
          document.write("<option value=\"" + states[hi] + "\">" + states[hi] + "</option>");
          document.getSelection(states);

   </script>
</select>
```

I've tried using this command: 
`document.getElementById("Label1").InnerHTML = states;` 
but it did not work. How to create a function that would give me the selected value in a label.text?
p.s. the dropdown menu is taken from www.hscripts.com

I forgot to mention that I have this menu in an update panel because I need a flicker free post back. when I click on my submit button the menu loses it's content, why?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
<select name="slist" id="slist">
   <script language="javascript">
      var states = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antarctica");
       for (var hi = 0; hi < states.length; hi++)
          document.write("<option value=\"" + states[hi] + "\">" + states[hi] + "</option>");
          document.getSelection(states);

       var sel = document.getElementById("slist");
       sel.addEventListener('change', function() {
          document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = sel.value;
       });
   </script>
</select>
<div id="Label1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For getting selected value after appending select box

```
var e = document.getElementById("slist");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; //Getting Value
document.getElementById("Label1").InnerHTML = strUser //Appending value to your label
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<select id="slist" name="slist" onchange="getSelectedState()">  
....................
</select>
```

*Your javascript function:*

```
function getSelectedState(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("slist"); //Get Element here
  var state = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text;   //Get  value from dropdown or you can get text also
  document.getElementById("selectedState").innerText = state; // initialize label here
}
```

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XrK4L/3/)

Comment: your answer does not supports him..!!

Comment: @Amarnath how can you say that?

Comment: have you seen his coding?? he said javascript dropdown..!!

Comment: @Amarnath Can you define javascript dropdown?

Comment: see he is getting the values through dropdown and not in the option as you have done. check his coding and then please provide appropriate solution